# Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have Rails 4.2 app, using bundler, rvm.

Added capybara and selenium-webdriver to Gemfile, bundle install ok.
I wrote small class that use selenium for some purpose:

```
require 'capybara'

class GoogleSite
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  end

  def find_all(param)
    url = 'https://google.com'
    visit url
  end
end

GoogleSite.new.find_all({v: "4"})
```

When I am calling it from **rails console** i got error:

> Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`,
>   please install the gem and add `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` to your
>   Gemfile if you are using bundler.
>   On line with "**visit url**"

When I call this script from **IRB** or by ruby file.rb, it's working fine but not from rails console when i include it in lib and call as a class.

I want to use capybara with poltergeist (rails controller will create sidekiq job that will call this class) but I am trying to debug with selenium (to see errors and correct form filling).